# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'org/bouncycastle/x509/CertPathReviewerMessages_de.properties'

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

All of sudden my flutter android project build is failing with the following errors.

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.LICENSE found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15on-1.65 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.65) and jetified-bcprov-jdk15to18-1.69 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.69)

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'org/bouncycastle/x509/CertPathReviewerMessages_de.properties'.

My gradle properties :
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Target and compile SDK's are 31. "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"

Flutter configuration:
Flutter 3.3.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ffccd96b62 (4 weeks ago) • 2022-08-29 17:28:57 -0700
Engine • revision 5e9e0e0aa8
Tools • Dart 2.18.0 • DevTools 2.15.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
**Apply following to your build.gradle,

```
android {
  ...
  configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'conceal'
    all*.exclude module: 'bcprov-jdk15on'
  }
}
```

Im also getting the same error
but the thing is I havent pushed the code on my git over a week.
It was working fine, Ive just ran it again after a week with same settings.
Even a month ago code having the same error

**Fvm Flutter Version 3.3.0 | 3.0.3**

**1: Task failed with an exception.**

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.LICENSE found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15on-1.65 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.65) and jetified-bcprov-jdk15to18-1.69 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.69)
> ...

**2: Task failed with an exception.**
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'org/bouncycastle/x509/CertPathReviewerMessages_de.properties'.